# windows 7 Task Scheduler to run Batch Script at user login only once at first login

Tags: file, batch-file, runonce

i have created a script and created a task scheduler to run in windows 7 when the user first time login. How to stop the script to run when the user log-off and log-in 2nd time. I dont want to delete this task because it has to run for another user also for the first login.

We have hundred of users and this script has to run on first log-in for every user.

Will really appreicate as i am stuck now.

Comment: You need to save some kind of flag and have the script check for the flag, i.e. save a file in the user profile. If it has to happen once for each user only, clearly it's doing something that you can recognise second time around.

Comment: Instead using Task Scheduler, it seems RunOnce registry key is more suitable for you: create entry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce (you can create .reg file to add it to registry, no need to use regedit.exe). The key will be deleted automatically after item is executed, at 1st login.